# network id used as default gateway.

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

my internet cafe gives me a working internet connection
(assigning me ip 10.0.1.11 255.255.255.0)
however it also assigns me a default gateway of 10.0.1.0
I am very puzzled that this works, as this is a network id rather than a host address.
Any explanation?

Answer (score 2):

Internet addressing and subnetting conventions and best practices have evolved over time. Originally any address that was not the broadcast address was a valid host address, including the zero host address. But some implementations didn’t like zero as a host address, so now it’s considered best practice not to use zero as a host address. But if you happen to have equipment that doesn’t treat the zero host address as anything special, you can use it and it will work, as you’ve seen.